# How to pass the drop down value in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am having text box and drop down,my problem is i have supplier and country two drop down,but its taking the supplier drop down value its only taking country drop down .(i am showing drop down data from database).any one tell me where i am went wrong

**html:**

```
<form name="welcomeDiv1" id="welcomeDiv1">

<select name="supplier" id="supplier" style="margin:122px 0 0 939px;background-color:#E8E8E8;width:100px;position: absolute;"> 
   <option value="">Select supplier</option>
<?php

$sqlsupplier=mysql_query("SELECT supplier_id  FROM supplier");


while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlsupplier))

{

    echo "<option value='" . $row['supplier_id'] . "'>" . $row['supplier_id'] . "</option>";
}  

   ?>


</select>


    <select id="country" name="country" style="margin:122px 0 0 511px;background-color:#E8E8E8;width:100px;position: absolute;" >
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php

            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT country  FROM globalnetwork";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<option value='" . $row['country'] . "'>" . $row['country'] . "</option>";
            }

        ?>
    </select>

</form>

  <img   src="/image/add-new.png" style="margin:116px 0 -5px 2659px;cursor:pointer;position: absolute;" class="billingadddet_button" >
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $(".billingadddet_button").click(function() {

    var CPH_GridView1_billingmonthid = $("#CPH_GridView1_billingmonthid").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_clientid = $("#CPH_GridView1_clientid").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_clientname=  $("#CPH_GridView1_clientname").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_billingyear=  $("#CPH_GridView1_billingyear").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_billingmonth =  $("#CPH_GridView1_billingmonth").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_country =  $("#country").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_supplier =  $("#supplier").val();

    var dataString = 'CPH_GridView1_billingmonthid='+ CPH_GridView1_billingmonthid +'&CPH_GridView1_clientid='+CPH_GridView1_clientid+'&CPH_GridView1_clientname='+CPH_GridView1_clientname+'&CPH_GridView1_billingyear='+CPH_GridView1_billingyear+'&CPH_GridView1_billingmonth='+CPH_GridView1_billingmonth+'&CPH_GridView1_country='+CPH_GridView1_country+'&CPH_GridView1_supplier='+CPH_GridView1_supplier;


    if(CPH_GridView1_clientid=='')
    {
    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else
    {
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insertdetailed.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#display").after(html);

    window.location = '?action=billingdatainputandexportdetailedreport';
    $("#flash").hide();
    }
    });
    } return false;
    });
    });
```

**insertdetailed.php**

```
$billingmonthid = $_POST['CPH_GridView1_billingmonthid'];
if(isSet($_POST['CPH_GridView1_billingmonthid']))

{
$billingmonthid = $_POST['CPH_GridView1_billingmonthid'];
$clientid=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_clientid'];
$clientname=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_clientname'];
$billingyear=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_billingyear'];
$billingmonth=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_billingmonth'];
$country=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_country'];
$supplier=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_supplier'];

$sql_insert="insert into billingdetailedreport(billingmonthid,clientid,clientname,billingyear,billingmonth,supplier,country) values ('$billingmonthid','$clientid','$clientname','$billingyear','$billingmonth','$supplier','$country')";
//print "Here";
print $sql_insert;
mysql_query($sql_insert);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$( "#country option:selected").val();
```

Same for Suplier

```
$( "#supplier option:selected").val();
```

Also I can suggest to use $( "#welcomeDiv1" ).serialize() and use it in ajax request

Hope this will help.